# how to use relative file path to read a file in java?

Tags: java

file path is not working, input1.txt is located in the same directory as library.java.
What should i do to correct it ?
How should i give path so that it read thr text file ?

```
package SimpleLibrarySystem;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
public class Library
{
ArrayList <Book> var = new ArrayList<Book>();
HashMap<Book, LocalDateTime> var1 = new HashMap<Book, LocalDateTime>();
public Library(String person, LocalDateTime time)
{
 try{
    File myfile = new File("input1.txt") ;
    Scanner br = new Scanner(myfile);
    String line = br.nextLine();

    while ((line != null))
    {

        String a = line;
        line = br.nextLine();
        String b = line;
        Book a1 = new Book(a,b,person);
        Book a2 = new Book (a,b, "");
        var.add(a2);
        var1.put(a1,time);
        //System.out.println(a + " "+ b);
        line = br.nextLine();
    }
    br.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        System.out.println("not working");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Paths are relative to the working directory, not to source files.

Comment: java.lang.System has a property: "user.dir" this is where the relative file path will be looked under

Comment: It's always a good idea to print the exception error message. E.g. with `e.printStackTrace()`.

Comment: If you use relative paths you can convert the relative path to an absolute path with File.getAbsolutePath() and print it for debugging purposes.

Comment: Bear in mind that you have no ultimate control of the location from where your app is run. Therefore you can't use relative paths with certainty

Answer (score 0):

[image: file tree]

with code:

```
public class Main{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            int counter = 0;

            try (FileReader fileReader = new FileReader("src/file.txt"); Scanner sc = new Scanner(fileReader)) {
                while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
                    ++counter;
                    sc.nextLine();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new IllegalStateException(e.getMessage());
            }
        System.out.println(counter);
        }
}
```

checkout: [how to read file in Java](https://www.baeldung.com/reading-file-in-java)